How to display product attributes with icon on the product catalogue page?
A client wants to add car tires to a WooCommerce based shop. For convenience, I would like to add tire attributes to the store view, such as in this example (show the icon and next to it the corresponding value):

The best I've been able to do at the moment:

I used How to display some attributes directly on shop page/product page in WooCommerce? answer code with the following attributes:
$attributes_names = array('Kandevõime (KG)', 'Keskava',);

How to display some product attributes with icons on shop pages?
